# Compare data between two date ranges in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date, join

Given me 2 date ranges (previous dates and current dates), and I wanna compare values of these 2 date ranges.

Comparison method:

- n-th day value of one date range comparing with n-th day value of another date range (e.g. value of 1st day of previous date range will be compared with value of 1st day of current date range, and so on)
- If the date does not exist in the table, display zero for the value.
- If 2 date ranges are not in same length, display NULL and zero to fill the gap.

**Example**

DB Table "data":

```
date         | value
-------------|------
2018-01-01   | 3
2018-01-02   | 5
2018-01-03   | 8
2018-01-04   | 6
2018-02-04   | 4
2018-02-05   | 2
2018-02-06   | 7
2018-02-07   | 0
```

Given date ranges: (Current) 2018-02-04 to 2018-02-07, (Previous) 2018-01-01 to 2018-01-03

Desired output:

```
curDate      | curValue | preDate     | preValue
-------------|----------|-------------|---------
2018-02-04   | 4        | 2018-01-01  | 3
2018-02-05   | 2        | 2018-01-02  | 5
2018-02-06   | 7        | 2018-01-03  | 8
2018-02-07   | 0        | NULL        | 0
```

I am now stuck in the join condition, and my current SQL is like:

```
DECLARE @currentStartDateTime  datetime   = '2018-02-04 00:00:00'
DECLARE @currentEndDateTime    datetime   = '2018-02-07 23:59:59'
DECLARE @previousStartDateTime datetime   = '2018-01-01 00:00:00'
DECLARE @previousEndDateTime   datetime   = '2018-01-03 23:59:59'

SELECT   cur.[date]             AS [curDate]
        ,ISNULL(cur.[total], 0) AS [curTotal]
        ,pre.[date]             AS [preDate]
        ,ISNULL(pre.[total], 0) AS [preTotal]
    FROM (
        SELECT * FROM [data] 
            WHERE [date] BETWEEN @currentStartDateTime AND @currentEndDateTime
    ) cur
    FULL OUTER JOIN (       
        SELECT * FROM [data] 
            WHERE [date] BETWEEN @previousStartDateTime AND @previousEndDateTime
    ) pre
        ON cur.[date] = DATEADD(day, 1, pre.[date]) -- <<< Stuck in this part
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing I would do is to create common table expressions for your date ranges, each having two columns: a column with the data value, and a column with row number value. This way, It's going to be very easy to join by n-th value.

So here is my suggested solution:

First, Create and populate sample table (**Please** save us this step in your future questions)

```
DECLARE @data As Table
(
    [date] DATE,
    [value] INT
);

INSERT INTO @data
VALUES
('2018-01-01', 3),
('2018-01-02', 5),
('2018-01-03', 8),
('2018-01-04', 6),
('2018-02-04', 4),
('2018-02-05', 2),
('2018-02-06', 7),
('2018-02-07', 0);
```

Now, I've changed your `@currentStartDateTime` from `2018-02-04` to `2018-02-03`, 
to make sure I also return rows that are not in the table (**Please** make sure your sample data covers all requierments)

```
DECLARE @currentStartDateTime  datetime   = '2018-02-03 00:00:00',
        @currentEndDateTime    datetime   = '2018-02-07 23:59:59',
        @previousStartDateTime datetime   = '2018-01-01 00:00:00',
        @previousEndDateTime   datetime   = '2018-01-03 23:59:59'
```

Now, my solution seems quite cumbersome because I wanted to show all steps in details. 
You might be able to simplify it.

First, calculate the max date difference in days.
Then, create a numbers cte from 1 to that difference + 1.
Then, create calendar ctes for each range,
Then a final cte to do a full join between the ranges,
and a select from that final cte left joined twice to the data table.

```
-- This allows us to use the smallest possible tally cte.
DECLARE @MaxDateDiff int;
SELECT @MaxDateDiff = MAX(d)
FROM (
    VALUES  (DATEDIFF(DAY, @currentStartDateTime, @currentEndDateTime)), 
            (DATEDIFF(DAY, @previousStartDateTime, @previousEndDateTime))
    ) v(d) -- I like table value constructors :-)

;WITH Tally AS 
(
    SELECT TOP (@MaxDateDiff + 1) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) As Number
    FROM sys.objects a
    -- if your database is very small (number of tables, procedures ect'), 
    -- you might want to unremark the next row
    -- CROSS JOIN sys.objects b
),
CurrentRange AS  
(
    SELECT DATEADD(DAY, Number-1, @currentStartDateTime) As [Date], Number
    FROM Tally
    -- we need the where clause in case the other range is bigger...
    WHERE DATEADD(DAY, Number-1, @currentStartDateTime) <= @currentEndDateTime
), 
PreviousRange AS 
(
    SELECT DATEADD(DAY, Number-1, @previousStartDateTime) As [Date], Number
    FROM Tally
    WHERE DATEADD(DAY, Number-1, @previousStartDateTime) <= @previousEndDateTime
), 
BothRanges AS 
(        
    SELECT C.Date As CurDate, P.Date As PreDate
    FROM CurrentRange As C
    FULL JOIN PreviousRange As P ON C.Number =  P.Number
)

SELECT CurDate, ISNULL(c.Value, 0) as CurValue, PreDate, ISNULL(p.Value, 0) as PreValue
FROM BothRanges
LEFT JOIN @data AS c ON CurDate = c.[Date]
LEFT JOIN @data AS p ON PreDate = p.[Date]
```

Results: (Remember that `@currentStartDateTime` is different than the one on the question)

```
CurDate                 CurValue    PreDate                 PreValue
03.02.2018 00:00:00     0           01.01.2018 00:00:00     3
04.02.2018 00:00:00     4           02.01.2018 00:00:00     5
05.02.2018 00:00:00     2           03.01.2018 00:00:00     8
06.02.2018 00:00:00     7           NULL                    0
07.02.2018 00:00:00     0           NULL                    0
```

[You can see a live demo on rextester.](http://rextester.com/IOE83741)

Comment: your result differs from the expected one

Comment: I know. It's Because my sample data is different. I've written in my answer that I've changed the `@currentStartDateTime` value. This is to include a row where the date exists in the range but not in the table. Check out the rextester link - you can change the variable value back to `'2018-02-04 00:00:00'` and see the results match the expected results.

Comment: sorry for my late response! I just got time to work on my sql, thanks so much for the advice, it works perfectly!

Comment: Glad to help :-)

Answer (score 1):

It is good practice to include all the DDLs and inserts together when you ask.

```
DROP TABLE data;
CREATE TABLE data
(
    date DATE,
    value INT
);
GO
INSERT INTO data
VALUES
('2018-01-01', 3),
('2018-01-02', 5),
('2018-01-03', 8),
('2018-01-04', 6),
('2018-02-04', 4),
('2018-02-05', 2),
('2018-02-06', 7),
('2018-02-07', 0);

DECLARE @currentStartDateTime DATETIME = '2018-02-04 00:00:00';
DECLARE @currentEndDateTime DATETIME = '2018-02-07 23:59:59';
DECLARE @previousStartDateTime DATETIME = '2018-01-01 00:00:00';
DECLARE @previousEndDateTime DATETIME = '2018-01-03 23:59:59';

SELECT a.date curDate,
       a.value curValue,
       b.date preDate,
       COALESCE(b.value, 0) preValue
FROM
(
    SELECT *,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY date) rn
    FROM data
    WHERE date
    BETWEEN @currentStartDateTime AND @currentEndDateTime
) a
    LEFT JOIN
    (
        SELECT *,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY date) rn
        FROM data
        WHERE date
        BETWEEN @previousStartDateTime AND @previousEndDateTime
    ) b
        ON a.rn = b.rn;
```

Comment: "It is good practice to include all the DDLs and inserts together when you ask." Very true, and nice answer, though it's wrong, since it will not produce dates that does not exist in the table (see the middle bullet in the question: "If the date does not exist in the table, display zero for the value.").

Comment: @ZoharPeled is there stated that is true for both left and right sides? I understood this task as if it not exists on the right side.

Comment: I might be wrong but I understood the OP wants every date inside the date ranges, even if that date does not appear in the actual table. If I understood the question correctly, the sample data is wrong since it doesn't provide any "missing" dates (I've mentioned it in my comment)